# get radio box value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I under the wrong impression that jquery or JS can retrieve the values of radio buttons in a form? The reason i ask is because in my code the script i use to check for all fields in a form, does not seem to recognise the value in `id="contact2"` in the form, which is a radio group. I have posted my code at jsfiddle.net and would appreciate some feedback as to how I can correct this. Many thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xGrb9/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
$('input:radio[name=bar]:checked').val();
```

Because of how radio buttons are checked/unchecked and their values are stored. (from the jQuery docs). You also need to make sure that the radio buttons have different IDs, which is a classic gotcha.

Finally, when testing if a radio button has not been selected at all, make sure to test against `undefined` and not an empty string for compatibility across browsers.

EDIT: looked at your code, and you need to do two things:
1. Change IDs of the buttons, to something like "contact2a" and "contact2b" so they are unique.
2. Change your `var customer2 =` line to `var contact2=$("input[name=contact2]:checked").val();`

Comment: would it then be a case of doing a if statement to determine the value? thanks

Comment: No, I tested your setup on jsfiddle with the code I listed (the new var contact2 =) line I provided along with changing the IDs of your radio buttons and it worked, with contact2 being populated as either "yes" or "no," i.e., having the value of the checked radio button.

Comment: i have updated the fiddle with new code and it seems to be not working. what is supposed to happen is that if the value of contact2 is blank (not selected) then it is supposed to trigger the error. that is not happening. http://jsfiddle.net/xGrb9/1/

Comment: Uh, you made a typo: "var contact2=var contact2=$("input[name=contact2]:checked").val();" should be "var contact2=$("input[name=contact2]:checked").val();" which makes it all work.

Comment: @shelhammer actually that was a typo in the fiddle, but i was testing on my machine and it seems to be working in reverse. if i tick one of the boxes it displays the error and if i leave unticked it sends the message. it shouldn't get that far and should throw the error message. http://jsfiddle.net/xGrb9/2/

Comment: @bollo, please read over your code carefully. I am testing it in your second fiddle, after having corrected your typo, and it works exactly as desired. Make sure your cache is also cleared and the like, and if you still have the problem comment again. The code I have presented is sound.

Comment: @bollo, although the code works as I have suggested, you may want to change the contact2 == "" to contact2 == undefined since this is a radio button and not a text input.

Comment: i hate to disagree with a knowledgeable programmer but it is not working. for example, in the second fiddle, if you do not check a box, it is supposed to throw the error the same way as if an input was blank. that isn't happening. i have just checked the fiddle again and i have cleared cache etc. thanks

Comment: putting in the undefined seemed to solve it. thanks very much foryour patience

Comment: No problem, sorry I didn't mention that earlier. Added it in my answer for others.

Comment: just a follow on. is there a reason that i have overlooked that would cause me to have to refresh the page after each form submission? for example, user fills form and no errors form gets sent and all values cleared. but in order to pass any value a second time i have to refresh browser?

Comment: Not that I see here. It sounds like your code (in its present state on your machine) might generate a javascript error and halt processing. I'd monitor the developer toolbar (such as firebug) output.

Comment: the first time I load the page, it sends fine and all values are cleared from the form. if a user completes the form a second time, no radio values are sent. firebug confirms this in the response tab.

Comment: Ok, but did you check the script errors tab? You should probably ask a new question, this discussion is getting long, and we don't know what your code is anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
 var contact2=$("#contact2").val();
```

to:

```
 var contact2=$('input[name="contact2"]:checked').val();
```

You need the checked because otherwise it finds both inputs.

Also, technically, all IDs should be unique, ie, not used on 2 elements on the page.

Comment: you and shelhamer posted the same answer at almost the same time. thank you

Comment: Except you can copy and paste mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use .val()

See this: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: This is the correct answer. Voting it down doesn't make sense! I didn't think much explanation is needed as I also provided the page where you can go to get more help on the .val() method!

Comment: Yes, providing the link to the val page is helpful, but it doesn't directly help solve bollo's problem. What's more helpful is to say what needs to be changed to make it work. If we all just posted links to documentation without any other details, it wouldn't be much help for others. (BTW, it wasn't me that down voted).

Answer (score 1):

Both of your radio buttons have the same ID. That doesn't work in HTML. You'll have to refer to the buttons separately and select the one that is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call

```
$("[name=contact2]:checked").val()
```